# InfluxDB 0.8.8 server startup returns no response

Tags: database, centos, server, time-series, influxdb

so I am trying to set up a influxdb server running on the same CentOS machine as a grafana server.  Currently when I launch the influxDB server, no data is returned.  So this is all the output I get:

`[07/21/15 17:12:21] [INFO] Loading configuration file config.sample.toml`

`+---------------------------------------------+
|  _____        __ _            _____  ____   |
| |_   _|      / _| |          |  __ \|  _ \  |
|   | |  _ __ | |_| |_   ___  _| |  | | |_) | |
|   | | | '_ \|  _| | | | \ \/ / |  | |  _ <  |
|  _| |_| | | | | | | |_| |>  <| |__| | |_) | |
| |_____|_| |_|_| |_|\__,_/_/\_\_____/|____/  |
+---------------------------------------------+`

I am wondering why it doesn't run the server.  It seems to quit out, but no error output is given...
here is the important bit of my config file:

```
# Welcome to the InfluxDB configuration file.

# If hostname (on the OS) doesn't return a name that can be resolved by the other
# systems in the cluster, you'll have to set the hostname to an IP or something
# that can be resolved here.
# hostname = ""

bind-address = "192.xxx.xxx.xx"

# Once every 24 hours InfluxDB will report anonymous data to m.influxdb.com
# The data includes raft name (random 8 bytes), os, arch and version
# We don't track ip addresses of servers reporting. This is only used
# to track the number of instances running and the versions which
# is very helpful for us.
# Change this option to true to disable reporting.
reporting-disabled = false

[logging]
# logging level can be one of "debug", "info", "warn" or "error"
level  = "info"
file   = "influxdb.log"         # stdout to log to standard out

# Configure the admin server
[admin]
port   = 8083              # binding is disabled if the port isn't set
assets = "./admin"

# Configure the http api
[api]
port     = 8086    # binding is disabled if the port isn't set
# ssl-port = 8084    # SSL support is enabled if you set a port and cert
# ssl-cert = "/path/to/cert.pem"

# connections will timeout after this amount of time. Ensures that clients that misbehave 
# and keep alive connections they don't use won't end up connection a million times.
# However, if a request is taking longer than this to complete, could be a problem.
read-timeout = "5s"

[input_plugins]

# Configure the graphite api
[input_plugins.graphite]
enabled = false
# port = 2003
# database = ""  # store graphite data in this database

# Raft configuration
[raft]
# The raft port should be open between all servers in a cluster.
# However, this port shouldn't be accessible from the internet.

port = 8090

# Where the raft logs are stored. The user running InfluxDB will need read/write access.
dir  = "/tmp/influxdb/development/raft"

# election-timeout = "1s"  

[storage]
dir = "/tmp/influxdb/development/db"
# How many requests to potentially buffer in memory. If the buffer gets filled then writes
# will still be logged and once the local storage has caught up (or compacted) the writes
# will be replayed from the WAL
write-buffer-size = 10000
...
```

any ideas as to why the service doesn't launch the server?
Edit: I am running Influxdb v0.8.8

Edit (log.txt):
`[2015/07/22 15:06:31 UTC] [INFO] (main.setupLogging:69) Redirectoring logging to /opt/influxdb/shared/log.txt
[2015/07/22 15:06:31 UTC] [INFO] (main.start:164) Starting Influx Server 0.8.8 bound to 0.0.0.0...
[2015/07/22 15:06:31 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/server.NewServer:43) Opening database at /opt/influxdb/shared/data/db
[2015/07/22 15:06:31 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/wal.NewWAL:40) Opening wal in /opt/influxdb/shared/data/wal
[2015/07/22 15:06:31 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/api/http.(*HttpServer).EnableSsl:74) Ssl will be disabled since the ssl port or certificate path weren't set
[2015/07/22 15:06:31 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/coordinator.(*RaftServer).Serve:566) Initializing Raft HTTP server
[2015/07/22 15:06:31 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/coordinator.(*RaftServer).Serve:576) Raft Server Listening at 0.0.0.0:8090
[2015/07/22 15:06:31 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/coordinator.(*RaftServer).startRaft:384) Initializing Raft Server: http://denlabapp0020.int.hidux.com:8090
[2015/07/22 15:06:31 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/coordinator.(*InfluxJoinCommand).Apply:252) Adding new server to the cluster config d41518a27d24777
[2015/07/22 15:06:31 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/cluster.(*ClusterConfiguration).AddPotentialServer:291) Added server to cluster config: 1, http://denlabapp0020.int.hidux.com:8090, denlabapp0020.int.hidux.com:8099
[2015/07/22 15:06:31 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/cluster.(*ClusterConfiguration).AddPotentialServer:292) Checking whether this is the local server local: denlabapp0020.int.hidux.com:8099, new: denlabapp0020.int.hidux.com:8099
[2015/07/22 15:06:31 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/cluster.(*ClusterConfiguration).AddPotentialServer:301) Added the local server
[2015/07/22 15:06:31 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/coordinator.(*RaftServer).startRaft:409) Recovered from log
[2015/07/22 15:06:31 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/server.(*Server).ListenAndServe:96) Waiting for local server to be added
[2015/07/22 15:06:31 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/wal.(*WAL).SetServerId:109) Setting server id to 1 and recovering
[2015/07/22 15:06:32 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/coordinator.(*RaftServer).raftEventHandler:448) (raft:d41518a27d24777) Selected as leader. Starting leader loop.
[2015/07/22 15:06:36 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/server.(*Server).ListenAndServe:128) Recovering from log...
[2015/07/22 15:06:36 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/cluster.NewWriteBuffer:30) local: Initializing write buffer with buffer size of 10000
[2015/07/22 15:06:36 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/cluster.(*ClusterConfiguration).RecoverFromWAL:1203) Waiting for servers to recover
[2015/07/22 15:06:36 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/coordinator.(*ProtobufServer).ListenAndServe:66) ProtobufServer listening on 0.0.0.0:8099
[2015/07/22 15:06:36 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/cluster.func·005:1185) Recovering local server
[2015/07/22 15:06:36 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/server.(*Server).ListenAndServe:133) recovered
[2015/07/22 15:06:36 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/coordinator.(*Coordinator).ConnectToProtobufServers:898) Connecting to other nodes in the cluster
[2015/07/22 15:06:36 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/server.(*Server).ListenAndServe:139) Starting admin interface on port 8083
[2015/07/22 15:06:36 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/server.(*Server).ListenAndServe:156) Graphite input plugins is disabled
[2015/07/22 15:06:36 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/server.(*Server).ListenAndServe:178) Collectd input plugins is disabled
[2015/07/22 15:06:36 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/server.(*Server).ListenAndServe:187) UDP server is disabled
[2015/07/22 15:06:36 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/server.(*Server).ListenAndServe:187) UDP server is disabled
[2015/07/22 15:06:36 UTC] [INFO] (github.com/influxdb/influxdb/server.(*Server).ListenAndServe:216) Starting Http Api server on port 8086`

Edit2:
It seems as though the service runs for a second, and then shutdown:
`-bash-4.1$ sudo service influxdb status
Setting ulimit -n 65536
influxdb Process is running [ OK ]
-bash-4.1$ sudo service influxdb status
Setting ulimit -n 65536
influxdb Process is not running [ FAILED ]`

Comment: What is in your log file? (probably in /opt/influxdb/shared/)

Comment: log.txt output added

Comment: I don't see anything amiss in the logs, but the startup message indicates you're running from the `config.sample.toml` configuration file. It could be that your startup script is calling the wrong config.

Did you edit the `config.sample.toml` file? Is that the one you are quoting in your post? Perhaps the process is starting up with the wrong config and exiting. Unfortunately for 0.8 I'm not 100% sure how to generate a new config or how to explicitly name the config path at startup. Happy to work with you on that if you email support@influxdb.com

Comment: config.sample.toml is the config file I have edited. I'm going to look into it a bit more to see if I can focus on what the issue is more.